# question about coherent ring

Tags: sheaf-theory

R is right coherent ring if every finite generated right ideal is finite presented.This is also equivalent to $\prod_SR$ is flat left R-module for any set $S$.
It is easy to see right Noetherian ring is right coherent.

1. Can someone give an example which is right coherent but not right Noetherian?
2. Is there any relation  between coherent ring and coherent sheaf? Does this definition come from algebraic geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard example for 1 is a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, this example is in the Wikipedia page for "coherent ring"... It is always best to look at the obvious places before asking a question!

Comment: Sorry.Maybe I tap wrong such that it is downvote.I can't chage this before you edit it.please pardon me for my error.

Comment: so I will close this.so ashamed!Sorry